# how to check if rar contains all files

Tags: windows-7, winrar

I was archiving 22gb folder it took hours. But then it ended abruptly, i couldn't tell if it finished or i pressed some key...as my computer went to sleep mode and to wake up i moved mouse and clicked.

How can i check if the folder A is what's in A.rar completely.

I have windows 7.

I know i can extract it and compare sizes..but is there other way?

Also while it was compressing it was saying compression ratio is 80% but filez size didn't go down by 80% instead it went down more like 20%.

Comment: [get a list of files with winrar command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684972/get-a-list-of-files-with-winrar-command-line)

Comment: `80%` means it's `80%` of the original size, not an `80%` decrease in size.